# Why does a reference to a trait in a generic function have to implement `Sized`?

Tags: reference, rust, traits

I have a function that returns a reference to a trait (`trait_ref()`) and another function that takes a reference to a generic trait implementation (`take_trait_ref_generic`).

However, it's not possible to pass the reference I get from the first function to the second one. Rustc complains that "the trait `std::marker::Sized` is not implemented for `SomeTrait`".

Even though that's true, why does it have to implement `Sized`? It's a reference anyway.

```
trait SomeTrait {}

struct TraitImpl;

impl SomeTrait for TraitImpl {}

struct Container {
    trait_impl: TraitImpl,
}

impl Container {
    fn trait_ref(&self) -> &SomeTrait {
        &self.trait_impl
    }
}

fn take_trait_ref_generic<T: SomeTrait>(generic_trait_ref: &T) {}

fn main() {
    let container = Container { trait_impl: TraitImpl };

    /*Not possible*/
    take_trait_ref_generic(container.trait_ref());
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, **all** generic types on functions implicitly have the `Sized` bound, regardless of how they are used. You need to explicitly opt-out of that requirement using `?Sized`:

```
fn take_trait_ref_generic<T>(generic_trait_ref: &T)
where 
    T: ?Sized + SomeTrait
{}
```

Comment: Ok is there a good reason for this rule? In other words, what would we lose if the compiler automatically added +?Sized on all bounds used only in references?