# Can I declare that implementations of a given trait should not be expected to be Sized?

Tags: rust, traits

I defined a trait `Foo`, implemented this trait for `[u32]`, and wrote a function `bar` taking this trait as argument ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=b20c6d9ae4503ac596a76ab66ea675e0&version=stable&mode=debug)):

```
trait Foo {
    fn foo(&self) -> u32;
}

impl Foo for [u32] {
    fn foo(&self) -> u32 {
        self[0]
    }
}

fn bar<T>(f: &T) -> u32
where
    T: Foo,
{
    f.foo() + 1
}

fn main() {
    let f: &[u32] = &[42];
    bar(f);
}
```

This does not compile because `bar` implicitly expects its arguments to be `Sized`:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `[u32]: std::marker::Sized` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:20:5
   |
20 |     bar(f);
   |     ^^^ `[u32]` does not have a constant size known at compile-time
   |
   = help: the trait `std::marker::Sized` is not implemented for `[u32]`
note: required by `bar`
  --> src/main.rs:11:1
   |
11 | / fn bar<T>(f: &T) -> u32
12 | | where
13 | |     T: Foo,
14 | | {
15 | |     f.foo() + 1
16 | | }
   | |_^
```

I can fix it with `T: Foo + ?Sized`, but then I would have to do this for *every* function expecting a `Foo`, which is a pain...

Can I declare once and for all that implementations of `Foo` should not be expected to be `Sized`? I tried `trait Foo: ?Sized` in line 1, but the compiler complains about it.

This question is not the same as [Trait implementing Sized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31515921). In that question, the `Foo` parameter is moved, so it is normal that the compiler wants to know its size at compile time. In my case, the parameter is a reference, so it does not *need* to be sized -- but still the compiler implicitly assumes it is, unless explicitly told (using `+ ?Sized`). What I would like to change is this implicit assumption, for this particular trait.

Answer (score 2):

## Why does the compiler complain about `trait Foo: ?Sized`?

> When you say that every `Foo` is `Sized`, you're kind of hiding the truth to yourself. Yes, every `Foo` is `Sized` but actually every type has a given size at some point. The real important information is that you're not saying how much this size is.

In this case you asking for a sized `[u32]`:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `[u32]: std::marker::Sized` is not satisfied
  |
  | impl Foo for [u32] {
  |      ^^^ `[u32]` does not have a constant size known at compile-time
  |
  = help: the trait `std::marker::Sized` is not implemented for `[u32]`
```

For further information consult [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31516384/3131852) of [*Trait implementing Sized*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31515921/trait-implementing-sized).

## Why can't `T` be unsized, since we only have a reference?

Let me quote again from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44344518/3131852) from [*Why does a reference to a trait in a generic function have to implement `Sized`?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44343818/why-does-a-reference-to-a-trait-in-a-generic-function-have-to-implement-sized/44344518#44344518)

> By default, **all** generic types on functions implicitly have the `Sized` bound, regardless of how they are used. You need to explicitly opt-out of that requirement using `?Sized`

This will solve your problem:

```
fn bar<T>(f: &T) -> u32
where
    T: Foo + ?Sized,
{
    f.foo() + 1
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=01bad768e9c0adea3d9949d336c54193&version=stable&mode=debug)

It would also be possible to implement `Foo` for `&[u32]`:

```
impl<'a> Foo for &'a [u32] {
    fn foo(&self) -> u32 {
        self[0]
    }
}

fn bar<T>(f: T) -> u32
where
    T: Foo,
{
    f.foo() + 1
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=dbe34aa553ebb1389270db8274717373&version=stable&mode=debug)

In this particular case, you could even generalize your implementation for `Foo` and it would work on `Vec`s and arrays as well as references to those types:

```
impl<T: AsRef<[u32]>> Foo for T {
    fn foo(&self) -> u32 {
        self.as_ref()[0]
    }
}
```

With the new [impl Trait](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1522-conservative-impl-trait.md) syntax, `bar` can be shortened in the last two cases to

```
fn bar(f: impl Foo) -> u32 {
    f.foo() + 1
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=48c657ed405ffd9e04d5ee432c8ccbdd&version=stable&mode=debug)

Comment: Please note, that the last notation is somewhat controversial, but I won't go into depth in this answer.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Re. the first part, I think you missed my point: I'm not trying to enforce Foo: Sized, but on the contrary, Foo: ?Sized (i.e. "Foo could be not Sized"). Re. the second part, I had the idea of implementing Foo for &[u32] but then I have to pass a &&[u32] to `bar`, which seemed a little awkward...

Comment: @Pierre-Antoine So did the answer solved your Problem, or not?

Comment: Not quite: it makes that particular example compile, but my goal was to let the compiler know that Foo+?Sized should be used anywhere I bind a type parameter to Foo. Apparently, this is not possible... :-(

Comment: @Pierre-Antoine No, this does not work. See both quotes in my answer. *all generic types on functions implicitly have the Sized bound, regardless of how they are used.* This implies, that you always need the bound.

Comment: @Pierre-Antoine Note that Tim's second example changed `bar` to take `T` instead of `&T`; therefore, no `&&` is required (`T` becomes `&[u32]`).