# How to implement a trait for any sequence of elements?

Tags: generics, rust, iterator, traits

I am trying to implement a trait for any sequence of elements, so that it will work for vectors, arrays and slices. So far I've tried several approaches, but I can't compile any of them :(

I have this trait, and a function that uses it, and a basic data type implementing the trait:

```
trait Hitable {
    fn hit(&self, val: f64) -> bool;
}

fn check_hit<T: Hitable>(world: &T) -> bool {
    world.hit(1.0)
}

struct Obj(f64);

impl Hitable for Obj {
    fn hit(&self, val: f64) -> bool {
        self.0 > val
    }
}
```

I'd like to be able to implement that trait for sequence of `Obj`'s.
It works fine if I just restrict it to vectors:

```
impl<T> Hitable for Vec<T>
where
    T: Hitable,
{
    fn hit(&self, val: f64) -> bool {
        self.iter().any(|h| h.hit(val))
    }
}

fn main() {
    let v = vec![Obj(2.0), Obj(3.0)];
    println!("{}", check_hit(&v));
}
```

But I want to make it more generic so that it works for arrays and slices; how can I do that?

I tried the following four attempts:

#### Attempt #1: for iterator on Hitables.

```
// It's not clear how to call it:
//    vec.iter().hit(...) does not compile
//    vec.into_iter().hit(...) does not compile
//
impl<T, U> Hitable for T
where
    T: Iterator<Item = U>,
    U: Hitable,
{
    fn hit(&self, val: f64) -> bool {
        self.any(|h| h.hit(val))
    }
}
```

#### Attempt #2: for something which can be turned into iterator.

```
// Does not compile as well:
//
//         self.into_iter().any(|h| h.hit(val))
//         ^^^^ cannot move out of borrowed content
//
impl<T, U> Hitable for T
where
    T: IntoIterator<Item = U>,
    U: Hitable,
{
    fn hit(&self, val: f64) -> bool {
        self.into_iter().any(|h| h.hit(val))
    }
}
```

#### Attempt #3: for slices.

```
// This usage doesn't compile:
//     let v = vec![Obj(2.0), Obj(3.0)];
//     println!("{}", check_hit(&v));
//
// It says that Hitable is not implemented for vectors.
// When I convert vector to slice, i.e. &v[..], complains about
// unknown size in compilation time.
impl<T> Hitable for [T]
where
    T: Hitable,
{
    fn hit(&self, val: f64) -> bool {
        self.iter().any(|h| h.hit(val))
    }
}
```

#### Attempt #4: for Iterator + Clone

```
//     let v = vec![Obj(2.0), Obj(3.0)];
//     println!("{}", check_hit(&v.iter()));
//
// does not compile:
//     println!("{}", check_hit(&v.iter()));
//                    ^^^^^^^^^ `&Obj` is not an iterator
//
impl<T, U> Hitable for T
where
    T: Iterator<Item = U> + Clone,
    U: Hitable,
{
    fn hit(&self, val: f64) -> bool {
        self.clone().any(|h| h.hit(val))
    }
}
```

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=85849423ff9cc95c3896a7d754215a1d)

Comment: `&self` — are you aware of the concept of mutability in Rust, as well as the fact that `Iterator::next` requires a mutable receiver?

Comment: `Hitable for T` ... `&self` — are you aware that references to types might implement different traits than the type itself?

Comment: @Shepmaster Yes, I think I understand those concepts. My trait doesn't need to mutate underlying value, so perhaps implementing it on iterators is not a good idea. Regarding your second point: I'm not quite sure what happens to the trait's function argument &self, when I implement the trait for some reference type &T. Will it be &&T? Should I dereference it? I'm using &self in the trait function to show that I only need read access (no taking ownership, no mutation)...

Comment: [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=6c46b4a5c7583ed274f3a228444f7d3a) , The working version here for into_iter(). and iter(). It is related with the mutability as @Shepmaster pointed.

Comment: @ÖmerErden Yes, thank you, it works now indeed. However, now when I realise that implementing it for iterator requires mutation I think that it's better to implement it on slices only, since the trait function shouldn't require mutation (it just reads the data).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### 1. `Iterator`-based

This cannot work because iterators need to be mutable in order to advance them, but your trait requires `&self`.

#### 2. `IntoIterator`-based

I'd change the trait to take `self` by value and then only implement it for references to `Obj`. This also allows implementing it for any type that implements `IntoIterator`:

```
trait Hitable {
    fn hit(self, val: f64) -> bool;
}

fn check_hit<T: Hitable>(world: T) -> bool {
    world.hit(1.0)
}

struct Obj(f64);

impl Hitable for &'_ Obj {
    fn hit(self, val: f64) -> bool {
        self.0 > val
    }
}

impl<I> Hitable for I
where
    I: IntoIterator,
    I::Item: Hitable,
{
    fn hit(self, val: f64) -> bool {
        self.into_iter().any(|h| h.hit(val))
    }
}

fn main() {
    let o = Obj(2.0);
    let v = vec![Obj(2.0), Obj(3.0)];

    println!("{}", check_hit(&o));
    println!("{}", check_hit(&v));
}
```

See also:

- [When should I not implement a trait for references to implementors of that trait?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28799372/155423)

#### 3. Slice-based

I find that reading the entire error message, not just the one line summary, can help:

```
error[E0277]: the size for values of type `[Obj]` cannot be known at compilation time
  --> src/main.rs:28:20
   |
28 |     println!("{}", check_hit(&v[..]));
   |                    ^^^^^^^^^ doesn't have a size known at compile-time
   |
   = help: the trait `std::marker::Sized` is not implemented for `[Obj]`
   = note: to learn more, visit <https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-04-advanced-types.html#dynamically-sized-types-and-the-sized-trait>
note: required by `check_hit`
  --> src/main.rs:5:1
   |
5  | fn check_hit<T: Hitable>(world: &T) -> bool {
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Specifically, this bit: **note: required by `check_hit`** — `check_hit` requires that `T` be `Sized`. Removing that restriction allows this version to work:

```
fn check_hit<T: Hitable + ?Sized>(world: &T) -> bool {
//                      ^~~~~~~~
    world.hit(1.0)
}
```

See also:

- [Why does a reference to a trait in a generic function have to implement `Sized`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44343818/155423)
- [What does the question mark mean in a type parameter bound?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30333607/155423)

Comment: Great, thank you! Yes, I've seen that error message and even checked the suggested link. However, I didn't understand where exactly I need to add `?Sized`, for some reason I though that I have to add it to the bounds in the trait implementation (I tried but it didn't help). Is this approach (i.e. implementing a trait on slices) considered the best for such a task?

Comment: @dying_sphynx I don't know about "best". I think both working solutions are reasonable.